# Cannot create Ruby project in Eclim (eclipse + vim): Unable to find nature for alias 'ruby'

Tags: ruby, eclipse, vim, eclipse-plugin, eclim

In order to use [eclim](http://eclim.org/) in VIM I've installed eclim (via arch linux [aur package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/eclim/)) and have installed [eclipse-dltk-ruby](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/eclipse-dltk-ruby/). I want to use it on server so my setup is headless.

But `:ProjectCreate ./ -n ruby` command still returns `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find nature for alias 'ruby'.  Supported aliases include: cpp=org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature, c=org.eclipse.cdt.core.cnature, c++=org.eclipse.cdt.core.ccnature while executing command (port: 9091): -editor vim -command project_create -"/home/user/" -n ruby`

Detailed logs in `eclimd`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find nature for alias 'ruby'.  Supported aliases include: 
        at org.eclim.plugin.core.project.ProjectManagement.create(ProjectManagement.java:156)
        at org.eclim.plugin.core.command.project.ProjectCreateCommand.execute(ProjectCreateCommand.java:
        at org.eclim.command.Main$1.run(Main.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3794)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3433)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:101
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:694)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
        at org.eclim.eclipse.EclimApplication.start(EclimApplication.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLaunche
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:10
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1488)
```

May be there should be some configuration for enabling that Ruby plugin in eclim (or Eclipse). But official installation guide doesn't mention it.

Anyway I can see Ruby section in config of Eclipse when I run Eclipse itself:

[image]

There are startup logs of `eclimd`: http://pastie.org/10750800